# need help in mysql database retrieving (unable to retrieve the current value)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with around 20 columns, what I am trying to do is retrieve values from database and send those values to a Web page.

So, by using`mysql_fetch_array()` I can get the first value entered in the database and by using `while(mysql_fetch_array())`, I am able to retrieve all the values in the database table, and by using `fwrite()`, i can even send the values to a file.

But the problem is if i use `while(mysql_fetch_array())`, all the values are getting retrieved; I only want the current(latest) value entered in the database to be sent to another page. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you please add your actual code? It makes it a lot easier to see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter your query to only get the desired result.  So for example let's say you have a timetamp filed in the database, do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `timestamp_field` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Obviously you could use ASC instead of DESC if you wanted the earlier date.  This same logic applies to other column types that you may want to sort as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are trying to send the LATEST value to another page, why are you running a query that receives all the values and not just the one you need? Is it possible to do something with a new field and check for the latest "date_created" value? So you will get something like:

```
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Now you will get only the latest value entered in your database. Of course you have to create the column: date_created ;)

Answer (score 0):

We have to keep in mind it is bandwidth plus time consume to fetch many data from server then sort or get our desire data from received data . In this kind of scenario we have to optimized our sql query to solved the problem of bandwidth and time.

I accept the sql query **written by MIKE**. It seems to me optimized for the problem what you are facing.

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY`timestamp_field`DESC LIMIT 1`

So, after getting data from above query you just output the data which will help you to decrease the bandwidth and time to fetch data from server [It's an serious issue because it is not matter for 5 to 10 row but if there have 100000000000 then it really matter].

Thanks for your important time.